# problemas com exec php

Tags: php, python, apache, windows

Fiz o seguinte comando no php

```
    $comando="C:\Python27\python.exe programa.py";
    echo $comando;
```

no arquivo python

```
    print resultado;
```

Essa variável resultado tem o conteudo formado em json

```
    {
       "algumacoisa":"algumacoisa"
    }
```

Quando faço pelo prompt de comandos:

```
    python.exe programa.py
```

Ele retorna corretamente o conteudo, mas quando faço com php

```
    php site.php
```

Ele só retorna a última linha do json que é apenas um

```
    }
```

Comment: não sou muito entendido sobre exec php, mas vc tentou com shell_exec?

Comment: shell_exec é pra linux

Comment: Eu uso shell_exec no windows, se está usando php provavelmente consegue também

Comment: Já consegui resolver, foi so usar o passthru

Comment: passthru($comando, $resultado);
        echo $resultado;

Comment: onde eu coloco que ta resolvido?

Comment: só deixa assim, ou então responde sua própria pergunta com a resposta que encontrou e marca sua resposta como a correta

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido

Deu certo usando o comando

```
    passthru($comando, $resultado); echo $resultado;
```